# Which winapi function will allow me to change logged in user's password?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm looking for a `winapi` function that will allow me to change current logged in user's password. In my case, I know current password of logged in user. I use Windows 7 Ultimate.

Thanks.

**Background**

The background will look weird, but I'm going to describe it for clarification. My personal home PC is used by several users (dad, sister, cousins etc.). I'm the only administrator of the PC. All others are standard user. All user accounts are password protected.

I don't like that other people use my account as they mess with anything. I always install all softwares from my account and also troubleshoot PC. When I'm away from my PC for several weeks, may be some other user need to install a software, or do something that require administrative right. For this reason they may need to use my account. There may be emergency cases, and I must allow the user to log into my account by giving account password.

I recently faced such a situation. Before leaving my PC for long time, I changed my regular password to something else. I'll change that again when I reach my PC.

So I'm thinking to write a tiny program that will run each time someone logs into my account. The program will only change current password to something else that I only know. In this case, if anyone logs into my account, installs something, logs out, and cannot logged back in as the password changes.

Suppose I set my account's password as `abcd`. When someone logs in, the program will change it to `abcde`. Next time may be `abc123` and so on.

Comment: Have a look at one of the "make me admin" scripts flying around. (This is the first one google threw at me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/193721.aspx.) Thy might be better suited to what you need.

Comment: @sbi, doesn't help. other users do not know how to use command prompts.

Comment: @Donotalo: So put a link to it on their desktop.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't give out your password. Don't allow other people to run as your account. Selectively grant other users the minimal permissions they need to do and no more. Revoke these permissions when you don't want them to be able to do these things.

Comment: Perhaps this should be re phrased as a question on server fault?

Comment: @Richard Cook: That will be great. Any link that led me to your solution? Also, I'm thinking that my program will automatically lock/log off after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for NetUserChangePassword().  Check this MSDN link for sample code:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151546

Comment: I tried `NetUserChangePassword(0, 0, (LPCWSTR) "ab", (LPCWSTR) "123456");`. and the returned value is `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD`. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you need to specify real UNICODE strings.  Try this: NetUserChangePassword(0, 0, L"ab", L"123456");

Answer (score 0):

You could use ADSI to connect to the local machine, get the user object and call the change password action.

MSDN doc on [`IADsUser::ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746341%28VS.85%29.aspx) has the following example.

The following "C++" code example shows how to change a user password.

```
HRESULT ChangePassword(
    IADsUser *pUser, 
    LPWSTR oldPasswd, 
    LPWSTR newPasswd)
{
    HRESULT hr=S_OK;
    if(!pUser) { return E_FAIL;}
    hr = pUser->ChangePassword(oldPasswd, newPasswd);
    printf("User password has been changed");
    return hr;
}
```

The following VB code example shows how to get the user and change a user password.

```
Dim usr As IADsUser
Dim szOldPass As String
Dim szNewPass As String

On Error GoTo Cleanup

' Fabrikam is the MSDN fictional domain - us '.' for localhost
Set usr = GetObject("WinNT://Fabrikam/JeffSmith,user")
' Add code to securely retrieve the old and new password.

usr.ChangePassword szOldPass, szNewPass

Cleanup:
    If (Err.Number<>0) Then
        MsgBox("An error has occurred. " & Err.Number)
    End If
    Set usr = Nothing
```

Comment: I've never used ADSI. I'll look into it and will return if I face any problem. :)